# Docker Hub login failed with status 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I am trying to login to Docker hub and pull an image. I tried for example

```
docker login store.docker.com
Username: myusername
Password: *****
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://store.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

And I tried

```
docker login hub.docker.com
Username: myusername
Password: ***
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

So both store.docker.com and hub.docker.com produce an error 404 not found. I can log in to https://hub.docker.com using a browser using `myusername`. So my account looks fine.

What is the secret to pulling images from Docker hub? Is there an instruction, tutorial or training that describes the details of pulling and uploading images?

I am on Ubuntu 18.04. I can pull and push images to my own registry but somehow I lost the ability to pull from Docker hub when it no longer allowed anonymous pull requests.

```
[myuser:~] 130 $ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90
```

As a workaround, is there a way to download images files? So I can upload to my own registry?

Answer (score 4):

You should just write

```
docker login
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the url, you should use https://index.docker.io. hub.docker.com and store.docker.com no longer work.